# Is there an adjective based on "Paesi Bassi"?

Tags: translation, difference, adjectives

I know, there is an adjective "*olandese*" when speaking about the Netherlands. But is there an adjective which derives from "*Paesi Bassi*" (and not from  *Olanda*)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Treccani the term would be ***[neerlandese](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/neerlandese/)*** which is mainly referred to the language, as a synonym of olandese.

> **neerlandése** (meno com. **nederlandése**) agg. e s. m. e f. [dal fr.
>   *néerlandais*, der. di *Néerland*, che è un adattamento di *Nederland*
>   (propr. «paese basso»), nome oland. dell’Olanda]. – Sinon. di
>   *olandese*, usato soprattutto per indicare ufficialmente la lingua, del
>   ramo germanico occidentale, parlata in Olanda e, accanto al francese,
>   in Belgio e in alcune zone della Francia nord-occid.; il termine
>   assomma quindi in sé le due denominazioni di *olandese* e di *fiammingo*,
>   tra le quali non ha luogo di essere una sostanziale distinzione,
>   almeno a livello di lingua ufficiale e letteraria (oggi si tende
>   infatti a parlare di *letteratura neerlandese* per tutte le opere
>   scritte in questa lingua, a prescindere dalla nazionalità dei loro
>   autori). Una versione semplificata del neerlandese è l’afrikaans,
>   parlato dai boeri stanziati nella Repubblica Sudafricana (dove è una
>   delle 11 lingue ufficiali, accanto all’inglese, allo zulu, ecc.,
>   proclamate tali in seguito all’abolizione dell’apartheid).

Moreover in [Treccani's synonyms and antonyms](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/neerlandese_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) you can find:

> **neerlandese** /ne:rlan'dese/ (anche **nederlandese**) [dal fr. *néerlandais*,
>   der. di *Néerland*, adattam. di *Nederland* (propr. "paese basso"), nome
>   oland. dell'Olanda]. - ■ agg. [dell'Olanda, relativo all'Olanda, spec.
>   in riferimento alla lingua] ≈ olandese. ■ s. m. 1. [lingua, del ramo
>   germanico occidentale, parlata in Olanda e, accanto al francese, in
>   Belgio e in alcune zone della Francia nord-orient.] ≈ olandese. 2.
>   (anche f.) [abitante dei Paesi Bassi] ≈ olandese.

so according to meaning 2. the adjective can also figuratively indicate an inhabitant of Paesi Bassi (or olandese).

You can also find an interesting article named [*Il neerlandese è olandese o belga?*](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/neerlandese-olandese-belga) on the Accademia della Crusca site.

Comment: This one is good. As i understand, it can't be used for indicating something other than the language or an inhabitant, right? F.e. it wouldn't be correct to say "la capitale neerlandese" or "la pittura neerlandese"?

Comment: I wouldn't say that anything, even in Treccani's definition, is against using it as applied to anything. It says “Sinon[imo] di _olandese_, usato soprattutto per indicare ufficialmente la lingua...”, that is, “Synonym of _olandese_, used **mainly** to officially mean the language...”. And indeed other dictionaries (such as Zingarelli or De Mauro), simply define it as “olandese”, marking it as less-used.

Comment: And indeed your examples, especially “pittura ne(d)erlandese” find several uses, also in academic publications.

Comment: [Qui](https://blocnotes.rivistatradurre.it/bookcity-milano-15-18-11/), all'interno del programma di una serie di incontri sulla traduzione, si parla di “letteratura nederlandese”, e mi sembra di averlo visto altre volte così, con la “d”.

Comment: (Sorry for the Italian in my previous comment: In [this programme of a series of meetings about translation](https://blocnotes.rivistatradurre.it/bookcity-milano-15-18-11/), “letteratura nederlandese” is mentioned, and I believe the spelling with a “d” is frequent in similar contexts.)

Comment: @RussoTuristo And the Italian name of the Royal Netherlands Institute in Rome is [Reale Istituto Neerlandese di Roma](https://www.knir.it/it/).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, *neerlandese* is the correct term, although it is not widely used in spoken language. Normally people do understand *olandese*, and given the overall geography knowledge, I would not use *fiammingo* (also because it is not the same culture, nor the same language).